# How can I disable the new super+arrow window screen aligning feature?

Tags: window, 23.10

I recently updated my Ubuntu desktop to the latest 23.10. Among the changes, the super+arrow keybinding that moves a focused window to the left, to the right, minimizes or maximizes, shows me a panel of running programs, e.g. Firefox, file explorer, Thunderbird, to select so that it tiles together with that program. Let's say I super-left Firefox to align to the left, then Ubuntu presents me to select Thunderbird or some other program to be aligned to the right of the screen. I can escape the selection with the esc key, however, I'd rather not have this feature at all. It isn't helpful and instead of having one effective keybinding, I also have to respond to it with another. Super+arrow should only align the window and no further action needs to be specified. Is there any way I could disable this feature?

Comment: Somehow the default behavior has changed on your system. Go to Gnome Settings → **Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts → Windows** and remove any non-default customizations.

Comment: How exactly can this be done?   Is there a "restore defaults" action somewhere?

Comment: Read the thread, the answer is there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, run the **Extensions** (`gnome-extensions-app`) application and disable **Ubuntu Tiling Assistant** (under the **Built-In** section).

Instead of disabling this extension, you can just go to the **Settings** of this extension and disable **Open after tiling a window** (under **Tiling Popup** section).

If this does not help, please follow my comment above: Go to Gnome **Settings → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts → Windows** and remove any non-default customizations.

Comment: Thanks, disabling the Ubuntu Tiling Assistant helped!

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was straight in the Ubuntu (Gnome) settings app:

> Ubuntu Desktop > Enhanced Tiling > Tiling Popup (disable this option)

You won't need gnome-extensions or other special things like command line magic.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that, should have been more thorough with checking the new settings out, thanks for mentioning! That was the option in question, indeed.

Comment: Same for me, had to land here, before checking settings in depth.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, according to my experience.